# Passing variable to ActiveSheet.Range

Tags: excel, vba

How to pass a variable to ActiveSheet.Range ? Example instead of hard coded to With ActiveSheet.Range("C2:H15"), now I want to replace C2 and H15 as variable, I've tried the code as below, but it seems doesn't work

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("StarRange:EndRange")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have defined these as:

```
Dim StarRange as String
Dim EndRange as String
```

and StarRange is "C2" and EndRange is "H15", then simply:

```
With ActiveSheet.Range(StarRange & ":" & EndRange)
```

Comment: + 1 simple as that :)

Comment: This is what I missing With ActiveSheet.Range(StarRange & ":" & EndRange).. Thanks a lot